# checkAngles() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'y'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я тут свой чит делаю, но при запуске пишет то, что мне не требуется...

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\maksa\OneDrive\Документы\Desktop\My Files\CheatForGmod\AimBot.py", line 154, in <module>
    AimBot()
  File "C:\Users\maksa\OneDrive\Документы\Desktop\My Files\CheatForGmod\AimBot.py", line 57, in AimBot
    checkAngles()
TypeError: checkAngles() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'y'
```

Код:

```
import keyboard, pymem, time, requests, sys, math
from pymem import process
from math import atan, pi, sqrt

dwLocalPlayer = 0xD8C2CC
m_flFlashMaxAlpha = 0xA41C
dwForceJump = 0x524DF04
m_fFlags = 0x104 
m_iHealth = 0x100
m_lifeState = 0x25F
m_flDefuseLength = 0x29A8
m_iShotsFired = 0xA390
dwEntityList = 0x4DA3FA4
dwClientState = 0x58EFE4
dwClientState_ViewAngles = 0x4D90
m_vecOrigin = 0x138
m_iTeamNum = 0xF4
m_bDormant = 0xED
m_vecViewOffset = 0x108
m_dwBoneMatrix = 0x26A8

try:
    pm = pymem.Pymem("csgo.exe")
    client = pymem.process.module_from_name(pm.process_handle, "client.dll").lpBaseOfDll
    engine = pymem.process.module_from_name(pm.process_handle, "engine.dll").lpBaseOfDll
except:
    print("Приложение csgo.exe не запущено!")
    sys.exit()

def AimBot():

    aimfov = 120

    def normalizeAngles(viewAngleX, viewAngleY):
        if viewAngleX > 89:
            viewAngleX -= 360
        if viewAngleX < -89:
            viewAngleX += 360
        if viewAngleY > 180:
            viewAngleY -= 360
        if viewAngleY < 180:
            viewAngleY += 360
        return viewAngleX, viewAngleY

    def checkAngles(x, y):
        if x > 89:
            return False
        elif x < -89:
            return False
        elif y > 360:
            return False
        elif y < -360:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    checkAngles()

    def nanchecker(first, second):
        if math.isman(first) or math.isman(second):
            return False
        else:
            return True

    nanchecker()

    def calc_distance(current_x, current_y, new_x, new_y):

        distancex = new_x - current_x
        if distancex < -89:
            distancex += 360
        elif distancex > 89:
            distancex -= 360
        if distancex < 0.0:
            distancex = -distancex
        
        distancey = new_y - current_y
        if distancey < -180:
            distancey += 360
        elif distancey > 180:
            distancey -= 360
        if distancey < 0.0:
            distancey = -distancex
        return distancex, distancey

    def calcangle(localpos1, localpos2, localpos3, enemypos1, enemypos2, enemypos3):
        try:
            delta_x = localpos1 - enemypos1
            delta_y = localpos2 - enemypos2
            delta_z = localpos3 - enemypos3
            hyp = sqrt(delta_x * delta_x + delta_y * delta_y + delta_z * delta_z)
            x = atan(delta_z / hyp) * 180 / pi
            y = atan(delta_y / delta_x) * 180 / pi
            if delta_x >= 0.0:
                y += 180.0
            return x, y
        except:
            pass

    def main():
        player = pm.read_int(client + dwLocalPlayer)
        engine_pointer = pm.read_int(engine + dwClientState)
        localTeam = pm.read_int(player + m_iTeamNum)

        while True:
            target = None
            olddistx = 111111111111
            olddisty = 111111111111

            for i in range(1, 32):
                entity = pm.read_int(client + dwEntityList + 1 * 0x10)

                if entity:
                    try:
                        entity_team_id = pm.read_int(entity + m_iTeamNum)
                        entity_hp = pm.read_int(entity + m_iHealth)
                        entity_dormant = pm.read_int(entity + m_bDormant)
                    except:
                        pass

                if localTeam != entity_team_id and entity_hp > 0:
                    entity_bones = pm.read_int(entity + m_dwBoneMatrix)
                    localpos_x_angles = pm.read_float(engine_pointer + dwClientState_ViewAngles)
                    localpos_y_angles = pm.read_float(engine_pointer + dwClientState_ViewAngles + 0x4)
                    localpos_z_angles = pm.read_float(player + m_vecViewOffset + 0x8)
                    localpos1 = pm.read_float(player + m_vecOrigin)
                    localpos2 = pm.read_float(player + m_vecOrigin + 4)
                    localpos3 = pm.read_float(player + m_vecOrigin + 8) + localpos_z_angles

                    try:
                        entitypos_x = pm.read_float(entity_bones + 0x30 * 8 + 0xC)
                        entitypos_y = pm.read_float(entity_bones + 0x30 * 8 + 0x1C)
                        entitypos_z = pm.read_float(entity_bones + 0x30 * 8 + 0x2C)
                    except:
                        continue

                    x, y = calcangle(localpos1, localpos2, localpos3, entitypos_x< entitypos_y, entitypos_z)
                    newdist_x, newdist_y = calc_distance(localpos_x_angles, localpos_y_angles, x, y)

                    if newdist_x < olddistx and newdist_y < olddisty and newdist_x <= aimfov and newdist_y <= aimfov:
                        target_x, target_y, target_z = entitypos_x, entitypos_y, entitypos_z
                        olddistx, olddisty = newdist_x, newdist_y
                        target, target_hp, target_dormant = entity, entity_hp, entity_dormant
                if keyboard.is_pressed('alt') and player:

                    if target and target_hp > 0 and not target_dormant:
                        x, y = calcangle(localpos1, localpos2, localpos3, target_x, target_y, target_z)
                        normalize_x, normalize_y = normalizeAngles(x, y)

                        pm.read_float(engine_pointer + dwClientState_ViewAngles, normalize_x)
                        pm.read_float(engine_pointer + dwClientState_ViewAngles + 0x4, normalize_y)

    main()
AimBot()
```

Comment: Ну вы же сами пишете функцию checkAngles, в которую нужно передать два аргумента (x и y), а потом сами же ее вызываете без аргументов: `checkAngles()`. Не понятно зачем вообще этот пустой вызов - результат его никак не используется. Просто удалите его.

Comment: Если я припишу их, то тогда он выдаст ошибку:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\maksa\OneDrive\Документы\Desktop\My Files\CheatForGmod\AimBot.py", line 154, in <module>
    AimBot()
  File "C:\Users\maksa\OneDrive\Документы\Desktop\My Files\CheatForGmod\AimBot.py", line 57, in AimBot
    checkAngles(x, y)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Comment: Нужно передать конкретные углы, которые нужно проверить, а не просто x и y. И потом еще результат как-то использовать, иначе этот вызов не имеет смысла.

Answer (score 1):

```
def checkAngles(x, y):
    pass

checkAngles()
```

У вас в ошибке всё чётко написано: функция требует два аргумента, а не получает ни одного. Либо сделайте у функции аргументы по-умолчанию, если это уместно, либо передавайте ей требуемые аргументы при вызове.